# How to remove NaN from a string in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg, nan

I have this array that is used by `Svg` to create a map. It contains one big string. The problem is that there are NaNs in the array and it is not able to read the array properly. How can I remove these NaNs?

```
Array [
  "M214.00002913287273,NaNL214.0000224099021,NaNL214.00002913287273,NaNL214.00002913287273,NaNL214.00011653149096,NaNL214.00011317000562,NaNL214.00011317000562,NaNL214.00000784346574,214.00018930549527L214.0000224099021,NaNL213.999936131779,213.99969560711412L213.999936131779,213.99969560711412L214.00011317000562,NaNL214.00002913287273 ...
]
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Where is this array coming from? It might be easier not to fill it with `NaN`s in the first place

Comment: This is a clear [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You think that by removing the `NaN`'s your path will work. It will not. It will result in invalid syntax (and a broken map). In order to fix this you have to remove all data points with invalid coordinates ***before feeding them to the map***.

Answer (score 1):

```
array = ["M214.00002913287273,NaNL214.0000224099021,NaNL214.00002913287273,NaNL214.00002913287273,NaNL214.00011653149096,NaNL214.00011317000562,NaNL214.00011317000562,NaNL214.00000784346574,214.00018930549527L214.0000224099021,NaNL213.999936131779,213.99969560711412L213.999936131779,213.99969560711412L214.00011317000562,NaNL214.00002913287273"]
```

you can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) this array and use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for each string

```
array = array.map(x => x.replace(/NaN/g,''))
```

```js
 array = ["M214.00002913287273,NaNL214.0000224099021,NaNL214.00002913287273,NaNL214.00002913287273,NaNL214.00011653149096,NaNL214.00011317000562,NaNL214.00011317000562,NaNL214.00000784346574,214.00018930549527L214.0000224099021,NaNL213.999936131779,213.99969560711412L213.999936131779,213.99969560711412L214.00011317000562,NaNL214.00002913287273"]
array = array.map(x => x.replace(/NaN/g,''))
document.documentElement.innerHTML = array
```

Comment: That won't leave you with a valid path.

Comment: @RobertLongson you commented both answers that it wont leave us with a valid path. I only answered the specific problem in the question, which is the NaN issue in JavaScript. Now define a valid path ? Because it's up to you to do that and I have no idea how SVG maps work

Comment: That's precisely why answering an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) is dangerous.

Comment: @RobertLongson then maybe you can contribute to this community with an answer that takes in consideration the XY thingy ?

Comment: The OP has [asked another question instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70794684/how-to-read-in-a-topojson-file-with-svg). Having said that it comes with an enormous external data file so the OP needs to cut that down first really.

Answer (score 0):

you can map over the array & replace the cprrupted strings like this

```js
const corruptedStrings = [
  "M214.00002913287273,NaNL214.0000224099021,NaNL214.00002913287273..."
];

const replaceWord = (originalWord, wordToMatch, newValue) => (
  originalWord.replace(new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'g'), newValue);
)

const cleanedStrings = corruptedStrings.map(str => replaceWord(str, 'NaN', ''));
```

Comment: That won't leave you with a valid path.